# Maintain YAML indentation while printing the contents of a file into that YAML (using bash scripting)

Tags: bash, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I need to print the contents of a python file into a YAML file, without the indentation of the YAML file getting messed up.  The part of the YAML file that's doing this is a description of the commands that will get passed into a Bash script, so **we need to accomplish this with Bash scripting syntax**.  For example, the following hard-coded code WORKS.  Notice how the "cat" line is outputting the conents of script.py with the appropriate indentation:

[image]

The trick is getting it into that format when trying to read the Python from another file.  In fact, in order to create that screenshot, I had to actually go into the file after it was generated and add a bunch of spaces so it looks correct.  After I added the spaces, the file worked as intended.  Here's what the incorrect output looks like BEFORE I manually edit it:

[image]

Interestingly, the first line of the python (green arrow) starts on the correct line.  But the remaining lines are all along the left margin and is incorrect (red arrow).

Here's the code I'm using to get my code (in script.py) into the buildspec:

Note: ${Script} is a reference to my script.py file.  This variable is getting set elsewhere in the file.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
  build:
    commands:
      - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
      - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
      - |
        cat >> scrypt.py <<EOL
        ${Script}
        EOL
```

Comment: Am I describing the case right that you are taking script.yml, replacing ${Script} with script.py contents, and then trying to run that python text as a build step?

Comment: Is there any other way to pass that script.py? Like maybe download it from somewhere and run?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  And there are other ways, but I'm specifically trying to do this with the NO_SOURCE option specified, so I don't need to download source from somewhere else, like an S3 bucket.

Comment: I re-vamped the question to reduce a lot of unnecessary noise and focus in on the issue.

Comment: It seems that the problem lies in a tool that inserts the variable. It inserts it verbatim, while you want it to be indented. You could try to reformat the script.py before it is inserted by the tool (adding enough indentation yourself to the content).

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Though I'd be worried about maintaining that.  Anyone who has an auto-formatting scripts turned on, or wants to be a good coding citizen and fix the supposedly "messed up" indentation of the python would inadvertently break it. Maybe looping through the python file one line at a time, and inserting the spacing as part of the loop would work?

Comment: You might get some luck by using `Fn::Split` to split script.py by the newline, and then `Fn::Join` to join with newline + indentation. Add some empty lines in the script above and below to make it work. Found the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html). Is this what you are using, right?

Comment: Why can't you put script.py into some git repo, if you are using git anyway there?

Comment: Hm, the split/join approach might work too.  Sounds like some tricky syntax, but worth investigating.  As for Git, the code is already in CodeCommit, so it's accessible with Git commands.  The question though is to figure out of this is possible using the current approach.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that the !Include function that was putting the contents of script.py in place of ${Script} didn't care that we were in an YAML file, so whenever there was a new line, it just throw them all the way to the left.

There were two ways to solve this.  First, we could simply add spaces to script.py itself, so when its value gets substituted into ${Script}, they land in the right place.

What we ended up doing through (since the first way was pretty hacky and hard to maintain) was to simply give up on trying to !Include the file, and intead just literally paste the entire script.py contents into the YAML file, exactly where ${Script} originally was.  So the result looked like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
  build:
    commands:
      - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
      - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
      - pip3 install --quiet boto3
      - pip3 install --quiet GitPython
      - |
        cat > script.py <<EOL
        import boto3
        import git
        etc. etc. etc.
        EOL
      - python script.py
```